# The issue about sending the second calling using `Adafruit_requests`

Tags: python, request, spotify, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

##### Hi everyone!

#### Introduction

I'm currently working on a project where I'm creating an independent controller to manage Spotify player using their API. The controller is intended to expose localhost for authorization with a Spotify account. All basic controller functions are to be executed using physical switches, and data will be displayed on a simple TFT display.

#### What I'm using

- `Raspberry Pi Pico WH` (main controller board)
- `CircuitPython` by *Adafruit* (Python software)
- Various Adafruit libraries (listed in code)

#### Problem

While writing the software, I encountered a rather strange issue that I don't fully understand.
When sending the second request to the API (using `HTTP-GET` protocols via the `Adafruit_requests` lib), the compiler reported a `critical memory error`. Placing the `request.get(...)` function within a `try-except` block only resulted in an empty error message.

Interestingly, this situation only occurs when sending a request to the Spotify API. For example, when I used `worldtimeapi` as the URL address, everything worked correctly, and I received a response in JSON format.

#### Here's my code:

```
import board, time
import os, json
import socketpool, wifi, ipaddress
import adafruit_requests, ssl
from adafruit_httpserver import Server, Request, Response, Redirect, FileResponse, GET, POST, Headers
from circuitpython_parse import urlencode

# Spotify API
# ****************************************************************
# Variables (...)

# Server
# ****************************************************************
ssid = os.getenv("WIFI_SSID")
password = os.getenv("WIFI_PASSWORD")

wifi.radio.connect(ssid, password)
pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)
requests = adafruit_requests.Session(pool, ssl.create_default_context())    # HTTP requests
server = Server(pool, "/static", debug=True)

# Routing
# ****************************************************************
@server.route("/")
def base(request: Request):
    return FileResponse(request, "index.html", "/public")


@server.route('/login')
def login(request: Request):
    scope = # (...)
    params = # (...)

    auth_url = f"https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?{urlencode(params)}"

    return Redirect(request, auth_url)


@server.route('/callback')
def callback(request: Request):
    if 'code' in request.query_params.fields:
        req_body = # (...)

        try:
            TOKEN_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
            response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data=req_body)  # Works fine
            token_info = response.json()
            response.close()

            global access_token, refresh_token, expires_at
            access_token = token_info['access_token']
            refresh_token = token_info['refresh_token']
            expires_at = time.time() + token_info['expires_in'])

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error-callback:\n", str(e))

        return Redirect(request, "/main")


@server.route('/main')
def main(request: Request):
    try:
        req_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"
        # req_url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London"   # Test Non-Spotify API
        req_headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"}

        response = requests.get(req_url, headers=req_headers)       # ERROR
        curr_playing = response.json()
        response.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error-main:\n", str(e))

    return FileResponse(request, "main.html", "/public")

# Main APP
# ****************************************************************
server.serve_forever(str(wifi.radio.ipv4_address)) # Start localhost

while True:
    # Code...
```

I don't understand what is causing this error.
I've tried many methods, but none of them helped.

- At first, I thought it might be a synchronization issue, but importing asyncio isn't possible because for some reason the module doesn't exist.
- It might be due to the limited memory of the RP Pico W (but I'm not sure about that).
- I also found a relatively similar thread [here](https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/5538), but it wasn't very helpful for me.

I would appreciate help, advice, suggestions, or tips.
Thank you in advance.